# MVC4 OData serializes long to JSON strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, odata

I am using the OData beta implementation included in .NET MVC4 and I'm experiencing a weird issue: all of `long` values are serialized into JSON strings, and not, like `int`s and `float`s, into regular numbers.

Since Javascript [should support](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19) `Int64` values is there a way to add a custom OData serialization method for `long` values only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that JSON says it should be at least a 64bit double precision number - so similar to double in C++. The problem with double is that the way it's stored doesn't mean that it can represent the full range of 64bit integers - which is what long is. So in short, not all long valid values can be written as JSON numbers without possible loss of precision when parsed by JSON compliant parsers.

For exactly this reason OData always writes long values a strings.

Comment: But is there a way to provide a custom serializer for long values?